# How do I make a 3D height map from this 2D heat map?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I would like to model this heatmap in 3D as a heigtmap where the brightest green points are the lowest and the brightest pink points are the tallest and black is in the middle. I have the numerical values that were used to generate the image. Also, the color information has to be maintained for the 3D printer to print it in color. I have very little 3D modeling experience and basically no programming experience but I am a fast and enthusiastic learner. I have also never used blender before. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

[image: heat map]

Comment: There are two obstacles here. First, make your image grayscale. White is high and black is low. Second, using that image, make it a 3D object. The first problem is not solved inside blender I think, rather photoshop.